# Umbraco Menu macro disappears first on page load

Tags: menu, macros, rendering, umbraco

Im using Umbraco 4 and have built a menu using a macro.  I have one issue though when I click on a menu item the entire macro disappears immediately, some time before the rest of the page disappears so the new page can render.  The new page renders the menu at the same time as the rest of the page though.
Any ideas on why this could be happening? 
cheers 
Jon

Comment: Hi, can you include your macro code or a bit more info about it. I.e. Is it xslt or a .net usercontrol. Are you using any JavaScript in the menu as this sounds like a client side issue. Does this behaviour occur in all browsers etc. 

T

Comment: hi its an xslt macro.   but its too big to fit into the comment box.
The macro is essentially this one http://www.netaddicts.be/articles/the-'ultimate-navigation'.aspx
with a few alterations.

Yes it occurs in FF, IE and Chrome.
thanks.
Jon

Comment: [link to the xslt macro](http://www.netaddicts.be/articles/the-'ultimate-navigation'.aspx)

Comment: http://www.netaddicts.be/articles/the-'ultimate-navigation'.aspx

Comment: Sorry dont know how to add urls to stackoverflow , i'll try again
"http://www.netaddicts.be/articles/the-'ultimate-navigation'.aspx"

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at the ultimate navigation package and I suspect the issue you are having is a client side scripting issue rather than an Umbraco one.

I note you have commented on the blog asking for support from the package writers. THey are probably your best bet here I.m afraid.

However as an alternative it's proably worth looking at this umbraco navigation package:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/cogworks---flexible-navigation

as this does not use javascript and it may solve your issue or at least give you some pointers on constructing your own navigation.

T